# Html.BeginForm -> passing ?myparam=something to Action - always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-parameters

I have a Partial view which looks like the following

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl], role = "form" }))
```

It is used to signin to my website.

Id like my users to be able to call
`http://example.com/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=somecontroller`

but my post data never includes the added parameter

**My GETAction looks like**

```
 public ActionResult SignIn(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

**My PostAction looks like**

```
 public ActionResult SignIn(SignInModel model, string ReturnUrl)
```

ReturnUrl is always null - because the form doesn't post my parameter.

**How do I get it to post the parameter?**

Comment: As Landeeyo noted below, you are using the wrong overload and adding the returnUrl as a html attribute, not a route value (check the html you are generating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong version of BeginForm method. Try this:

SignIn.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Second", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, role = "form" }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @ViewBag.ReturnUrl

    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class SecondController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Second/

        public ActionResult SignIn(string ReturnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn(SignInModel model, string ReturnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway I don't know why you are using route values instead of just defining some field in the form...

Comment: It already have the HttpPost attribute - i just didn't include it in my question. (I thought it be obvious that i had HttpPost when i used form post :))

Comment: Have you tried @using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = "test" })) and public ActionResult SignIn(string ReturnUrl)?

Comment: I'm asking because I think the model binder have problems to bind the parameters because they don't match in an easy way.